# When to use Python special methods?

Tags: python

I know that classes can implement various special methods, such as `__iter__`, `__setitem__`, `__len__`, `__setattr__`, and many others. But when should I use them? Can anyone describe typical scenarios when I would want to implement them and they would simplify programming in Python?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you basically answered your question.

Become familiar with the special methods.  If you find that using one will make your program simpler, use it.  If you don't understand what one is for, or feel like it is a more complex solution - you have answered the question. Don't use it.

The typical scenarios are :

- Overriding operators
- Catching access to attributes that don't exist and dealing with that access (`__getattr__`)
- Manipulating class and instance creation (`__init__`, `__slots__`, `__new__`)
- Customizing string representations (`__str__` and `__repr__`)
- allowing callability (`__call__`)
- Hooking into convenient/well-used builtin syntax (`__getitem__`, `__len__`, etc...)

These are mostly covered at https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames and http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Comment: @Joe, you ask (maybe rhetorically?) "why implement __iter__" -- the answer is, obviously, to allow an instance of your class to be the `x` in some `for item in x: ...` loop, as is typically done with container classes.  *How* you implement `__iter__` may well be with `yield`s, but it's weird to think that an answer to "how" implies anything at all about "why!_)

Comment: Indeed. I had just overlooked this usage, I guess I have only rarely needed to emulate container types....

Answer (score 3):

Well, the short answer is: *when you need them*.

Since there are a lot of built in functions I can't answer for all of them. However, you can almost all the time manage without ever overriding a builtin Python function.

Usually when you *do* need them is when you'd like your object to behave like a builtin datatype in Python. For example if you'd like to be able to run

```
len(...)
```

on your object (override _____len_____(...)), or compare two objects of your datatypes like so:

```
obj1 < obj2
```

(override _____cmp_____(...)) to do this.

Comment: By the way, here is the documentation of the special Python functions if you don't have that: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: specifically http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a class that should act sort of like an array or dictionary, these are very useful so that your syntax looks familiar. For example, if you wanted to create an ordered dictionary, you could use all of the functions you mentioned so that you could interchange that with a regular dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`getattr` and `setattr` are useful when you want to implement an interface by delegating to an instance member instead of straight inheritance.  You map them to the `getattr` and `setattr` of the member.